# expand 1d numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to expand/repeat each element in a 1D array for different times

```
x = array([7,1,9])  #1d array
rep_size = array([3,2,2]) # repeat number for each element in x
result = arary([7,7,7,1,1,9,9]) #expected result
```

Is there a numpy function can do this if I don't want to use a for loop. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`numpy.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html):

```
result = np.repeat(x, rep_size)
```

output: `array([7, 7, 7, 1, 1, 9, 9])`